# Single Website Suddenly Unaccessable on my Comcast Network

Tags: networking, internet, routing

All,

I have a favorite website....http://69.27.184.62:8901. It's a shortwave radio remote receiver site called KFS SDR (I'm a ham radio operator). I've been visiting the site for over 2 years. The site is up and running and many of my friends access it just fine.

About 2 weeks ago it became inaccessible on my home network. I am directly connected to my Comcast gateway (No WiFi). 5 computers and 3 different browsers. No luck.

If I take a laptop to another network, say Starbucks, it works fine and operates normally.

I've disabled the Xfinity XFI Advanced Security. No luck.

I've cleared cache on the browsers. No luck.

One interesting data point......My cellphone uses cellular data from ATT. If I go out of my home, connect to the problem site on another WiFi network, I can access it. However, if I bring my phone home, connect to my WiFi network, it does NOT work. If I then return to ATT cellular data, I still can't access it. I have to leave my home network, reconnect to another WiFi, and it works again.

This leads me to believe that there is something on my home Comcast network that is "changing" or "editing" my network settings. These settings appear to be "reset' when I go outside my home to another network.

Is this a routing table problem?

Comcast has told me they have "whitelisted" the site and that is should work. It DOES NOT. They've basically told me it's my problem and have given up.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue.  Have you tried switching your DNS away from DNS provided by comcast?

Comment: Thank you! Just tried Google's DNS, 8.8.8.8. I also completely reset Firefox to DEFAULT settings and tried again. Unfortunately, no luck.

Comment: Try performing a trace route to the website. Still suspect a DNS issue, and it’s not due to the fact it’s an IP address, since domains are for our benefit.

Comment: Tried trace route....It hangs/timesout at the 24 hop....appears to make it all the way to the ISP that hosts the site "coastside.net"

Comment: Interestingly, the site I'm having trouble accessing has a "sister" site....69.27.184.58:8080. I have no trouble seeing this one. Traceroute gets me there in 24 hops.